# Dotted connector line between column of HighCharts column chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, highcharts

[image]

I want to create a column chart using HighCharts where i have to connect first two column with a dotted line which shows the difference between both the column.

Currently i am using HighCharts to draw this chart, but if we can achieve the same functionality in D3.js so I am open to change library.

Comment: In Highcharts you can do it in multiple ways, one idea is to add new line series for this dashed line: http://jsfiddle.net/6ww5yux4/ Another idea is to use chart.renderer.path in your case. Here you can find an example of highchairs with renderer methods: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/renderer

Comment: A very similar question was asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38738973/highcharts-bar-chart-and-datalabels-showing-difference. I'm connecting the two in case a solution is given for either.