# Highcharts Bar chart and datalabels showing difference

Tags: highcharts

can you please tell me whether the labels showing the difference is possible in Highcharts? See image here:

[image]

if yes can you please give me a few keywords to look at?

Comment: I think that you can do it in multiple ways, one idea is to add new line series for this line: http://jsfiddle.net/6ww5yux4 Another idea is to use chart.renderer.path in your case. Here you can find an example of highchairs with renderer methods: http://highcharts.com/demo/renderer

Comment: do you need the lines as well? or just labels showing the difference?

Comment: A very similar question was asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38718187/dotted-connector-line-between-column-of-highcharts-column-chart. I'm connecting the two in case a solution is given for either.

Comment: the lines would be a nice-to-have but this is no blocker actually